# Elasticsearch issue: Cannot connect AWS elasticsearch service

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, searchkick

I have a issue about configure elasticsearch to connect AWS elasticsearch service to run project in production.
My Gemfile:

```
    gem 'searchkick'
    gem 'faraday_middleware-aws-signers-v4'
    gem 'aws-sdk', '~> 2'
    gem "elasticsearch", ">= 1.0.15"
```

Reference: https://github.com/ankane/searchkick

My config/initializers/elasticsearch.rb file:

```
    require "faraday_middleware/aws_signers_v4"
    ENV["ELASTICSEARCH_URL"] = "https://search-eaterybot-u3yjm6cdn3ogkmv3bcdl5j7poy.ap-southeast-1.es.amazonaws.com/"

       Searchkick.client = Elasticsearch::Client.new(
       url: ENV["ELASTICSEARCH_URL"],
        transport_options: {request: {timeout: 10}}
       ) do |f|
       f.request :aws_signers_v4, {credentials: Aws::Credentials.new(Rails.application.secrets.aws_access_key_id, Rails.application.secrets.aws_secret_access_key),
       service_name: "es",
       region: "ap-southeast-1"
     }
   end
```

When I run "rake searchkick:reindex:all", it show error:

> Elasticsearch::Transport::Transport::Errors::Forbidden: [403]     {"message":"The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.\n\nThe Canonical String for this request should have been\n'GET\n/_aliases\n\naccept-encoding:gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3\nhost:search-eaterybot-u3yjm6cdn3ogkmv3bcdl5j7poy.ap-southeast-1.es.amazonaws.com\nx-amz-content-sha256:e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855\nx-amz-date:20160914T095023Z\n\naccept-encoding;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date\ne3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855'\n\nThe String-to-Sign should have been\n'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256\n20160914T095023Z\n20160914/ap-southeast-1/es/aws4_request\n47bc69b4440a13aeac990b8c6c49934f1dcc4693bbbda577bfdeb02e685c507b'\n"}"

Anyone can help me! Thanks!

Comment: Your credentials don't match! Do you have the right key?

Comment: Thank for response!
I checked, It's correct!
Please, help me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should exclude tailing slash from `ELASTICSEARCH_URL`

Comment: Oh, God! Waste me lots of time. Finally find the reason.